# WCF: recursive calls to service

Tags: c#, wcf, recursion

I have a WCF service.

```
[ServiceContract(ConfigurationName="WebEntityService")]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(WcfEntityService.TH.Category))]
public interface IEntityService {
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void ScanEntity(ScanInfo scanInfo, WebEntityBase entity);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class EntityService : IEntityService {
   [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
   public void ScanEntity(ScanInfo scanInfo, WebEntityBase entity) {
       try {
           WebScanner webScanner = new WebScanner(entity);
           webScanner.Scan(scanInfo);
           }
       catch (Exception) {
                throw;
            }
        }
}
```

The WcfEntityService.TH.Category class is inherited from WebEntityBase and placed in a different assembly. This class has the service reference to the WCF service and it calls ScanEntity recursively.

The problem is following.
When the WcfEntityService.TH.Category class calls ScanEntity I occur a serialization error.

> Type 'WcfEntityService.TH.Category' with data contract name 'Category:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfEntityService.TH' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Can anybody say there is any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please post the code of your data contracts?

Comment: This is an extraction from the code:
   [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public abstract class WebEntityBase : IWebEntity {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Uri {
            get { return Url.AbsoluteUri; }
            set { Url = value != null ? new Uri(value) : null; }
        }
 }

Comment: [DataContract(IsReference=true)]
    public abstract class WebCategory : WebEntityBase, IWebEntity {
        private WebCategory parentCategory;
        [DataMember]
        public WebCategory ParentCategory {
            get {
                return parentCategory;
            }
            set {
                if (value != null) {
                    parentCategory = value;
                    parentCategory.SubCategories.Add(this);
                }
            }
        }
   }

Comment: namespace WcfEntityService.TH {
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class Category : WebCategory, IWebEntity { ... }
 }